# Why am I getting a Java NoSuchPortException when the port exists?

Tags: java, serial-port

Got the following production code below, I'm using it for a new driver.  portName is COM4 and this port exists on the PC (and I can connect to it with hyperterminal), so why does Javacomm throw a NoSuchPortException?  COM4 shows up fine in device mgr. too

```
    final String portName = getSerialPort();
    try {
        final CommPortIdentifier id = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        port = (SerialPort) id.open(getName(), 1000);
    } catch (NoSuchPortException nspe) {
        report(SeverityCode.LEVEL2, getName(), "PIN Pad is not connected to " + portName + " port, or the port does not exist.");
        return;
    } catch (PortInUseException piue) {
        report(SeverityCode.LEVEL2, getName(), portName + " port is already in-use by some other device. Reason: " + piue.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enumerating the list of ports that are available on your system using the `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` and print what's listed. Are you sure that you installed the jarfiles and dll in the correct folders? If yes, then try adding COM4 using  `CommPortIdentifier.addPortName(java.lang.String portName, int portType, CommDriver driver)` .You can set the driver parameter to null to use the default driver.