# getting a javax.comm.NoSuchPortException when the port exist

Tags: java, serial-port

Hello I have seen this [Why am I getting a Java NoSuchPortException when the port exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026804/why-am-i-getting-a-java-nosuchportexception-when-the-port-exists) post but It's not very clear to me!!

In device manager it shows COM3 is exist and I can connect it through putty, but this piece of code is getting this error/exception.

```
try {
       portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");
    } catch (NoSuchPortException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
    }

try {
     serialPort = (SerialPort)portId.open("S2CFrameWork", 5000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

this simple code thrown a javax.comm.NoSuchPortException, I have also tried this with using Enumeration to get the list of avilable port but still it shows exception. Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Which bit of that code ?

Comment: portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");

Comment: So what did `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` show?

Comment: It's strange because `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` shouldn't throw `NoSuchPortException`. Post you code with `getPortIdentifiers()` call and first several lines from exception stack trace. And print exception with `ex.printTraceTrace()` don't use `System.out.println(ex)`.

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee Have you read carefully, I mean `getPortIdentifiers()`, note the trailing "s", which is different from the method you call in your code.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi Its showing an empty Enumeration.

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee, what OS do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### comm.jar should be placed in:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/lib

%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext
```

### win32com.dll should be placed in:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin

%JAVA_HOME%/jre/bin

%windir%System32
```

### javax.comm.properties should be placed in:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/lib

%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib
```

Comment: Where can i download this package for windows?

Comment: I have tried given instructions with [link](http://kishor15389.blogspot.rs/2011/05/how-to-install-java-communications.html) and it worked. Instructions for installation and file can be found with given link.

Comment: forgot to mention, link was copied from another thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562565/how-to-get-javax-comm-api)