# How to find Com PORT Id in Ubuntu ?

Tags: java, serial-port

I have plugged the USB Dongle in one port of my PC, which is running on the Ubuntu Machine, Now i need to find which port the USB Dongle is connected to. In windows normally it is detecting in COM4, now i need to find what is the PORT i need to use for Ubuntu OS. can anyone please help.

All i need is, to connect through USB dongle from the java program. I'm using RXTXComm.jar.

Code i'm using to connect:

```
portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/ttyUSB0");
```

Always i'm getting

```
NoSuchPort Exception only.
```

I have tried using , `ttyUSB0/ttyUSB1/ttyUSB2` like that. but no use. can anyone please help me how can i find the port id in ubuntu machine.

Comment: Hi #Frederic Close thanks for the formatting

Comment: If you type `ls /dev` at the command prompt do you see `ttyUSBn` in the listing?

Comment: Yes it is present, but when i tried to use that, getting the same exception. NoSuchPort Exception

Comment: Hm, does this post help you at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026804/why-am-i-getting-a-java-nosuchportexception-when-the-port-exists

Comment: Hi All i got the answer. Actually the code above is working. the problem is i was running this on the normal user. The program should be in root user / root group. Now i can able to access the ports. Thanks All